# User-level scheduling and tracking of boost threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, scheduling

I have a C++ application written for Linux in which multiple `boost::thread`s compete for access to a resource locked by a mutex. In order for my application to work correctly, most of these threads need to access the resource at fairly regular intervals. Some threads write to/refresh/update the resource, while others use it for computation or display. I can tolerate some leeway/drift, but not too much (e.g. if a thread should ideally access a resource every 0.2s, I can wait for maybe another 0.1s occasionally).

I've given a small example of this below:

```
pair<int,int> coordinates; //some shared resource (more complex in reality)
boost::mutex m; //mutex controlling access to resource

void Func1() {

  while(1) {
    usleep(1.0*1e6);
    boost::scoped_lock sl(m);
    ComputeUsingCoordinates(coordinates);

  }
}

void Func2() {
  while(1) {
    usleep(1.2*1e6);
    pair<int,int> newCoords = GetCoordinatesAcrossNetwork(); //receives update remotely
    boost::scoped_lock sl(m);
    coordinates = newCoords; //update local value of coordinates
  }
}

void Func3() {
  while(1) {
    usleep(0.5*1e6);
    boost::scoped_lock sl(m);
    Draw(coordinates); //draws coordinates on a screen
  }

}

void OtherComputation () {

  while(1) {
    //Some other computation that doesn't access the common resource, but is nevertheless competing for the CPU
  }

}

int main() {
  boost::thread thread1 = boost::thread(Func1);
  boost::thread thread2 = boost::thread(Func2);
  boost::thread thread3 = boost::thread(Func3);

  // ... other threads not accessing the resource
  boost::thread thread4 = boost::thread(OtherComputation); 
}
```

Currently, I see that some threads are being starved. In order to mitigate this issue, I force each thread to sleep between consecutive accesses to the resource. By making different threads sleep for different times, I enforce an ad-hoc scheduling policy. This seems to work well when there is a small number of threads, but as I add threading to different parts of the application, the starvation issue seems to crop up more and more frequently.

Is there:

- a way to keep track of /gather data on which threads are running, and when, how long threads are starved, etc. so that I can adjust the `usleep` time intervals
- a way to control access to the mutex so that a given thread cannot have consecutive accesses to it too frequently
- some other better way to schedule different threads at the application level in order to prevent starvation

Using a real-time OS/kernel is not an option for me. At present, I also cannot use C++11 (we will migrate to C++11, but only a few months from now at the earliest).

Comment: Do all the operations, (Compute, Draw etc), require all the Coordinate data when they run?  Do they all mutate the Coordinate data and, if so , do they always need access to all of it? The thing is, locks are best kept short and yours don't seem to fit that category:)   More details please.

Comment: A priority-based threadpool may provide a single location for scheduling policy and logic, as well as provide the ability to perform tracking, prevent consecutive access, etc.  The operations would be scheduled with the threadpool rather than dedicated to a given thread.  This shift in approach may also reveal areas where contention can be avoided.  For example, a compute operation only needs scheduled when receive has been executed, or a draw operation can use cached coordinates if new coordinates have not been computed.

Comment: @MartinJames Operations that read the coordinate data (Compute, Draw, etc) read all of it. Operations that mutate the data (currently, only Func2 which receives the update from across a network and updates the local copy) don't usually mutate all of it, but they can depending on how frequently data is sent.

I agree about the short locks. My rule of thumb was to lock as coarse-grain as possible and then refine as necessary. I guess I'm getting to that point.

Comment: @TannerSansbury Am I correct in saying that a thread pool is more useful to scenarios where threads are constantly getting started and finished? A thread pool was just supposed to mitigate the thread creation overhead, I thought. My scenario is a little different - most threads are created near the start of the program and last for its entire lifetime (10-15min). When I said "add threading to different parts of the application", I meant as as I add more and more objects to my code that utilize threads internally.

Comment: If order is especially important, or if randomly choosing an order will work, have you considered using boost condition variables? Based on how you set it up, you can have it randomly select the next thread based on multiple conditions (mainly if statements), or set it so that when one ends, the next on a pre-made "circle" will be called.

Comment: @maditya: I have always viewed the mitigation of thread creation overhead as a consequence rather than the purpose of the pattern.  A threadpool can provide a centralized location to schedule work based on heuristics, such as priority, last time executed, time waited, etc.  It may provide finer control and maintainability rather than depending on non-deterministic scheduling approaches, such as sleep or priority inversions.